# Pythonic way in loading multiple directories

Tags: python

I have a directories tree as below

Definition:

1. folder A contains folder B
2. Folder B contains folder C and first.py
3. Folder C contains inner.py

   folder_A -> folder_B -> 1. first.py 2. Folder_C -> inner.py

   folder_A -> folder_F -> config.ini

   folder_A -> folder_H -> 1. calc.py 2. Folder_I -> total.py

```
    folder_A
    ├── folder_B
    │   ├── first.py
    │   └── folder_C
    │       └── inner.py
    ├── folder_F
    │   └── config.ini
    └── folder_H
        ├── calc.py
        └── folder_I
            └── total.py
```

If lets say I am writing code in "inner.py". How can I just use a single code to always load Folder_A position and then from there just choose folder_{x} based on my preference?

My current code:

```
MAIN_PATH = '../../folder_F'
os.path.join(MAIN_PATH, 'config.ini')
# I do not wish to use the "../" but a more pythonic or advance way. Is there a cleaner way to do so?
```

Please also aware that before folder_A. There might be many folder and deeper load into folder A.

Example:

Folder_king -> Folder_G -> folder_A(now only here.)

Reason for not trying to use "../" is because my "inner.py" might be stored in a more deeper folder. If example inside 10x folder then it will be "../../../../../../../../../../folder_F/config.ini"???

Comment: It's not clear what you think is wrong with `../`. After all, you're looking for the parent of the parent of the current folder. Why do you want to avoid using that syntax?

Comment: I wish to learn multiple ways of handling situation like this. The method "../" has nothing wrong but it just dont feel too clean in my sense. For example, If i have a deeeeeeep folder for storing "inner.py" then I will have like many "../", isnt it? In which I dont think its a clean way to do it. Thats why I seek an answer here if possible.

Comment: you can always use absolute paths - if you are in `C:\A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\your.py` you can use `C:\A\` to adress it using absolute paths. With relatives paths, make sure you got the right one, depending on how/where you call your script your "path you are in" might not be what you think it to be

Comment: but if i use 'C:\A' then what if I this code will be used by others and example, my "C:\A\B\C\folder_A" but others might be "C:\A\folder_A" directly right?

Comment: Let us say you choose to find the path of folder A by getting current script's folder and going up the tree... how would you know that you've arrived at folder A? By the name of the project? Any identifying tag?

Comment: But is there a way to just set a PATH = 'folder_A'. so that anytime I load, i  just need to us os.path.join(PATH, 'folder_F')??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the use of `..` in itself. However, if the overall path is a relative paths, then it will be relative to the process's current working directory rather than the directory where the script is located.  You can avoid this problem by using `__file__` to obtain the path of the script itself (which could still be a relative path), and working from there.

```
MAIN_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../')
os.path.join(MAIN_PATH, 'folder_F/config.ini')
```

If you are particularly keen to avoid `..` appearing in the output path unnecessarily, then you can call `os.path.normpath` on a path containing `..` elements and it will simplify the path. For example:

```
MAIN_PATH = os.path.normpath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../'))

os.path.join(MAIN_PATH, 'folder_F/config.ini')
```

---

(Note - the trailing `/` on `MAIN_PATH` above is not strictly necessary, although it would make it more forgiving if you later append a subdirectory path using string concatenation instead of of `os.path.join`.)

Comment: thank you, this is another working way of doing it too.

Comment: Is there a way to set the MAIN_PATH to be pointing to "folder_A" which is the beginning of all the other folders?

Comment: @asker Yes if that's what you want. I'll change my answer to reflect this.